# Websocket configuration not working in apache server after changing ip to dns name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, websocket, dns, mod-proxy

We are using apache server as a proxy server for redirecting HTTP as well as Websocket requests. Websocket requests were working fine as long as we use apache server's ipaddress as below:

```
ws://<ipaddress>/app/systemNotifications/450/c3zym9e6/websocket
```

But when we change the ipaddress to domain name, websocket connection is not getting established with the url below:

```
ws://<domain-name>/app/systemNotifications/450/c3zym9e6/websocket
```

The error we recieved is :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://<domain-name>/app/systemNotifications/450/c3zym9e6/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

Please find the below configuration for redirecting websocket requests in apache server(httpd.conf file):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} ^websocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://<destination-server-ip>:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Comment: Is this rewrite inside <VirtualHost>?

Comment: No its outside of <virtualhost>

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?